# Prove that if $f(x)$ grows faster than a set of functions, it grows faster than their sum.

Tags: limits, functions

Let's say you have a function $f(x)$ and a finite set of functions $\{g_0(x), g_1(x), g_2(x), \ldots\}$.

If $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g_0(x)} = \infty,  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g_1(x)} = \infty, \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g_2(x)} = \infty, \text{ etc.}\ldots$$

Is it true then that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g_0(x) + g_1(x) + g_2(x) + \cdots} = \infty ?$$

And if it is, **how would you go about proving it**?

Comment: If $f/g\to\infty$ what does that say about $g/f$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, $g/f \to 0$? I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Now if $g_1/f\to0$ and $g_2/f\to0$ what does that say about $(g_1+g_2)/f$? And then what does _that_ say about $f/(g_1+g_2)$?

Comment: I guess you're saying that $g_1/f \to 0$ and $g_2/f \to 0$ implies that $(g_1 +g_2)/f \to 0$, which means that $f/(g_1 + g_2) \to \infty$, but I'm not sure how to prove that either, and I'm not sure why you would go through that step in order to prove the final case (the one in the OP).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're not sure about, unless you're wondering what the sum of two functions has to do with the sum of $n$ functions. _If_ that's what's puzzling you, the point is just that the sum of two functions was easier to type - $n$ functions works out the same.

Comment: Are the $g_k$ positive?

Comment: @copper.hat, by positive do you mean that their range/image is restricted to positive real numbers? I guess I thought that theorem would hold for any set of functions.

Comment: I mean is $g_k(x) >0$ for all $k$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: What about the case where $g_0 = 0.5f$ and $g_1 = 0.75f $ wouldn't that be a counter example?

Comment: That would require $g_0(x)$ to approach $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity. Wouldn't $0$ being added a finite number of times also equal $0$, therefore making this somewhat obviously true? *Please correct me if I am wrong.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L>0$ and choose $M$ such that if $x > M$ then
$f(x) \ge n L g_k(x)$. Hence
$\sum_k f(x) = n f(x) \ge n L \sum_k g_k(x)$ and so
$f(x) \ge L \sum_k g_k(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{f(x)}{g_0(x) + g_1(x) + g_2(x) + \cdots} \ge \frac{f(x)}{n\cdot \max(g_0(x), g_1(x), g_2(x), \cdots)}$$

where $n$ is how many $g_i$ functions there are.

Comment: I presume you mean to have , rather than $+$ in the denominator on the right?

Comment: This answer is quite unclear and I'm surprised that it's been up-voted twice.  Did you mean $\max\{g_0(x), g_1(x), g_2(x),\ldots\}$ (a function of $x$) or $\max\limits_x (g_0(x) + g_1(x)+g_2(x)+\cdots)$ (which is NOT a function of $x$) or something else? $\qquad$

Comment: I think this is supposed to have commas instead of addition. If that's fixed, I'll up vote.

Comment: You need to show that the right hand side diverges to infinity with or without +/,.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been upvoted, it is not clear even with the suggested edit.

Comment: Fixed, I think.

Comment: @ajotatxe: The equation is correct, but why does the right hand side converge to $\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{x\to \infty}g_i(x)/f(x)=0$ for $i=0,...,n$ then $0=\sum_{i=0}^n \lim_{x\to \infty}g_i(x)/f(x)=$ $=\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^n g_i(x)/f(x).$